# How to use the jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js script better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I have a lot of questions and would appreciate your help answering them. I've spent hours trying to figure this all out on my own but couldn't fix the problem.

My question is, when I inspect element in Google Chrome and try to add a new chunk of code to the script like this:

```
$("body").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"rounded-dots",
    **scrollInertia: 10**
});
```

why do I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I really can't add anything extra. I can't type javascript, I can only edit the code that I find.

This is the script I use: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

**My 'workable' code:** http://pastebin.com/sCDHwYAW 
If I add anything new it doesn't work anymore. Also the textarea doesn't show the custombar even if I have an height of 100% like the body width as well.

I would also like if I could get the image to load, the scroll speed increased and the scroll bar working in other places other than the body element. It would be perfect.

Comment: create a snippet to see what u do.

Comment: @Legends what do you mean? I add the code you see in the pastebin in the footer of phpbb after jquery is loaded.

Comment: Ok, can you debug pastebin? If you want help make it easy for users to just copy paste your code to test what's wrong, i.e. using snippets or jsFiddle

Comment: I've figured out some things since we last spoke. The only thing I haven't figured out is how to get it to work on a textarea on phpbb. I've copied the code of the example [link](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/textarea_example.html) on my board exactly as its put in the example with the js code and div wrapped arond it but it doesn't work.  @Legends

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting the syntax error because of the asterisks surrounding the second property.

Try changing it to this:

```
$("body").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"rounded-dots",
    scrollInertia: 10
});
```